# Phone keeps going into Fastboot after water damage

Tags: water-damage

My rooted Xiaomi Mi 5s plus refuses to boot into the system after I dropped it in water. I can boot it into TWRP recovery, and all of my files are still there, so I don't think that any files are damaged.

After it was damaged I quickly shut it off and when I turned it back on it simply refused to boot into the OS.

Any idea of what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Volume button is short-circuited, let it dry for few weeks. meanwhile you can boot phone with `fastboot continue`

Comment: yes, it turns out the volume button was damaged. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

volume button or PCB area that connected with volume button Flex or sorrounding components, it is depend on damage caused by water leakage and carbon, need to service or clean the part very soon,